# Want to use a single database and single table (wp_posts and wp_postmeta) for two different sites

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

I am currently working on a project where I need to setup a theme and plugin which has same database and table for wordpress
tables are:
**wp_posts
wp_postmeta**

I can edit these file as well as wordpress core files to achieve this task

**Need:**
that new wp_common_posts and wp_common_postmeta table should look and work exactly like wp_posts and wp_postmet, repectively

I don't want to use any other additional theme(s) or plugin(s)

Comment: This is interesting. To clarify, you want to use the same database for two different websites. If they are on the same host. You could try editing the config file to access the same database using the same prefix as per this link: https://www.morewordpress.com/yes-two-wordpress-sites-can-share-a-database-heres-how.   I am not sure if this would work. I would use headless wordpress to generate content for a non wordpress site.